# Custom field - display even when no value set

Tags: jira

I added a non-mandatory custom filed in JIRA, but the field is displayed only when the value is set via the Edit Issue screen.

The 'Where is my field' helper says: *The field 'Story URL' does not have value for issue XXX-1234 and will not be displayed on the view issue page. Set value for that field so that it shows up.*

I would like the field to be shown even if the value is not set. Is this possible?

This is so the field is visible and so it can be added using the inline editor (you can edit it inline once it's set).

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the default value to your field? :) That way it will always have a value defined and will be displayed.

Answer (score 2):

Since Jira 9.9, empty fields can be configured to be always shown, using the Configure screen page, via Project Settings > Screens. Click the screen name, and there will be a new column 'Show when empty', with an option that can be set for each field.

This feature requires Data Center or Cloud.

https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-2997

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-articles/Introducing-the-new-Empty-custom-field-configuration-feature-for/ba-p/2379469

https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftware/jira-software-9-9-x-release-notes-1236934945.html#JiraSoftware9.9.xreleasenotes-show-empty-fields