# Display a custom field even when no value is set

Tags: jira

**Note**: This question is essentially a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18627875/custom-field-display-even-when-no-value-set), however, the accepted answer of "Try adding a default value" doesn't really work for me for reasons I describe below.

I added a non-mandatory custom filed in JIRA, but the field is displayed only when the value is set via the Edit Issue screen.

The 'Where is my field' helper says: The field 'Story URL' does not have value for issue XXX-1234 and will not be displayed on the view issue page. Set value for that field so that it shows up.

I would like the field to be shown even if the value is not set. Is this possible?

This is so the field is visible and so it can be added using the inline editor (you can edit it inline once it's set).

The reason the answer of "Set a default value" is that my field is a set of labels and so there is no obvious value I can use as a default. I could create a pretend label called "None" or something, but that's a bit rubbish from a UX point-of view.

Comment: I'm afraid but seems you cant. Here a link to an atlassian discussion about this problem https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/Always-display-custom-field-in-issue-view/qaq-p/515379

Comment: That's what I feared. I'd seen similar answers, but yours has the bug tracker links so is particularly useful :-)

Comment: I guess the JIRA way of doing this is to show the custom field on a screen on each state transition, so I'll probably do that.